# implement a websocket pong frame using openssl in c

Tags: c, websocket

I have a websockt client which refers to this webpage :

```
  http://amitmason.blogspot.com/2019/03/c-https-client.html
```

and modify it to :

```
 int main() {
    char msg[1024]="GET /stream?streams=btcusdt@aggTrade HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                   "Host: fstream.binance.com\r\n"
                   "Sec-WebSocket-Key: hutBuLVguzbdZyp+3RpcylHOp8zngavG\r\n"
                   "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                   "Connection: Upgrade\r\n\r\n";

    sessionTLS tls = connectIP("54.249.113.172",443);
    writeTLS(tls, msg, strlen(msg));
    while(1){
        char buf[1024]={0} ;
        int bytes = readTLS(tls, buf, sizeof(buf));
        //do something in buf  
        fflush(stdout);
     }//while
     freeTLS(tls);
}//main

int writeTLS(sessionTLS &tls, char *msg, int len) { return SSL_write(tls.ssl, msg, len); }

int readTLS(sessionTLS &tls, char *buf, int len) {
    static int flag=0;
    int iret = SSL_read(tls.ssl, buf, len);
    if( iret < 100 || flag==1 ){
        hexdump( (unsigned char*) buf , iret );
        printf("(%d)\n",iret);
        flag=1 ;
    }
    return iret ;
}


void hexdump(unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
    size_t i,n=0;
    unsigned char c;
    while(n < len) {
        fprintf(stdout,"%08x ", (int)n);
        for(i=0; i < 16; i++) {
            c = (n+i < len) ? buf[n+i] : 0;
            if (n+i < len) fprintf(stdout,"%.2x ", c);
            else fprintf(stdout, "   ");
        }
        for(i=0; i < 16; i++) {
            c = (n+i < len) ? buf[n+i] : ' ';
            if (c < 0x20 || c > 0x7e) c = '.';
            fprintf(stdout,"%c",c);
        }
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
        n += 16;
    }
} // hexdump
```

This works fine , but I have to recv pings frame and pong frame back to websocket server , the following is what I received :

```
00000000 89 0d 31 35 39 31 32 32 38 39 35 34 38 39 32    ..1591228954892
(15)
00000000 81 7e 00 b4 7b 22 73 74 72 65 61 6d 22 3a 22 62 .~..{"stream":"b
00000010 74 63 75 73 64 74 40 61 67 67 54 72 61 64 65 22 tcusdt@aggTrade"
00000020 2c 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a 7b 22 65 22 3a 22 61 67 ,"data":{"e":"ag
00000030 67 54 72 61 64 65 22 2c 22 45 22 3a 31 35 39 31 gTrade","E":1591
00000040 32 32 38 39 35 35 34 33 37 2c 22 61 22 3a 31 30 228955437,"a":10
00000050 31 30 37 30 39 36 32 2c 22 73 22 3a 22 42 54 43 1070962,"s":"BTC
00000060 55 53 44 54 22 2c 22 70 22 3a 22 39 36 36 31 2e USDT","p":"9661.
00000070 39 30 22 2c 22 71 22 3a 22 30 2e 30 30 32 22 2c 90","q":"0.002",
00000080 22 66 22 3a 31 34 30 32 34 36 38 37 39 2c 22 6c "f":140246879,"l
00000090 22 3a 31 34 30 32 34 36 38 38 30 2c 22 54 22 3a ":140246880,"T":
000000a0 31 35 39 31 32 32 38 39 35 35 33 34 36 2c 22 6d 1591228955346,"m
000000b0 22 3a 74 72 75 65 7d 7d                         ":true}}
(184)
```

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Pings_and_Pongs_The_Heartbeat_of_WebSockets

```
00000000 89 0d 31 35 39 31 32 32 38 39 35 34 38 39 32    ..1591228954892
(15)
```

This message is ping frame , totally 15 bytes in this frame , All I have to do 
is to make a pong frame and send back to websocket server the data should be 0xA in opcode , so it should be :

```
8a 0d 31 35 39 31 32 32 38 39 35 34 38 39 32
```

All I need to do is send this 15 bytes pong frame back to websocket server .

My Question :

I can't call SSL_write to send this pong frame , because it is a message with
header of pong control code(0xA) , not a normal frame ,  so I need to have another
function to handle with this pong frame specially , what should I do so that this

```
8a 0d 31 35 39 31 32 32 38 39 35 34 38 39 32
```

15 bytes pong frame would send back to websocket server correctly and won't recv

```
00000000 88 0e 03 f0 50 6f 6e 67 20 74 69 6d 65 6f 75 74 ....Pong timeout
```

at the end .

I can't find any function of openssl which I can use like SSL_write which can
send pong data frame correctly , any suggestions are great appreciated !!

Edit :

```
int writePongTLS(sessionTLS &tls, unsigned char *msg, int len) { return SSL_write(tls.ssl, msg, len); }
```

and in function readTLS :

```
    unsigned char* checkflag = (unsigned char*) (buf+0) ;
    if( (*checkflag & 0x09) == 9 ){
        unsigned char pongmsg[256]={0} ;
        memcpy(pongmsg,buf,iret);
        pongmsg[0] = 0x8a ;
        writePongTLS(tls,pongmsg,iret);
        printf("send pong to websocket server \n");
        hexdump( (unsigned char*) pongmsg , iret );
        printf("\n\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```

look like it works perfectly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider reading the code from [WebSocket parsers / formatters out in the wild](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/c2091e9b29aca1fce27ed81dd3a876dad0bc3024/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h) and see how [the implementation deals with a `ping`](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/c2091e9b29aca1fce27ed81dd3a876dad0bc3024/lib/facil/http/websockets.c#L173-L190).

In general, your attempt seems to have missed one protocol detail and a possible concurrency concern.

#### Client Message Masking

> All I have to do is to make a pong frame and send back to WebSocket server the data should be 0xA in opcode , so it should be...

This approach of simply changing the opcode won't work because WebSocket clients **must** mask their data according to the protocol specification.

This means that your message header needs 4 more bytes (for the mask), the masking bit should be set and the content of your message should be XOR-ed with the mask.

Might as well **extract the `ping` message (if there is any) and re-wrap it**.

#### Outgoing Buffer - Frame Injection Errors

You might consider using an internal outgoing "user land" buffer rather than calling the `SSL_write` functions directly.

This is because of the possibility of frame injection errors if your client code is multi-threaded or even evented in a way that might allow the  `ping` frame to be written between frames that aren't fully written.

Note that the `write` family of functions (even with SSL) might not write all the data, which might require you to wait until your network peer (the server, in your case) ACKs some data in the TCP/IP stack's buffer.

this behavior could result in a race condition between two `write` calls, where both calls wait to insert their data into network's outgoing buffer.

This race condition could result in one frame being written in the middle of another.